# How do you get the visual element inside a ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I have a list of States in an ItemsControl, the DataTemplate is a CheckBox.  I would like to add a function to select(check) all states. However I need to loop through the CheckBoxs rather then the data items since the checked state is stored in a separate data structure then the list of states the ItemsControl's ItemSource is bound to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data template I subscribed to the checkbox's onload event. And in the event handler I add the checkbox reference to a generic list of checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Have a property in your DataObject called IsChecked and bind that to the Checkbox in DataTemplate(Default is TwoWay)

Comment: ItemContainnerGenerater is not a member of ItemsControl in Silverlight.

Comment: Oops sorry I didnt notice the Silverlight :)